# How to fix azure permission load page error?

Tags: azure, react.js

This is my event log

```
2019-09-04T23:29:47  Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service. The default timeout is 2 hours. Change the timeout with the App Setting SCM_LOGSTREAM_TIMEOUT (in seconds).
```

IIS Detailed Error - 403.14 - Forbidden

#### HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden

The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory.Most likely causes:

- A default document is not configured for the requested URL, and directory browsing is not enabled on the server.

Things you can try:

- If you do not want to enable directory browsing, ensure that a default document is configured and that the file exists.
- Enable directory browsing using IIS Manager.

  1. Open IIS Manager.
  2. In the Features view, double-click Directory Browsing.
  3. On the Directory Browsing page, in the Actions pane, click Enable.
- Verify that the configuration/system.webServer/directoryBrowse@enabled attribute is set to true in the site or application configuration file.

Detailed Error Information:Module   DirectoryListingModuleNotification   ExecuteRequestHandlerHandler   StaticFileError Code   0x00000000
Requested URL   https://marcial:80/Physical Path   D:\home\site\wwwrootLogon Method   AnonymousLogon User   Anonymous

More Information:This error occurs when a document is not specified in the URL, no default document is specified for the Web site or application, and directory listing is not enabled for the Web site or application. This setting may be disabled on purpose to secure the contents of the server.

[View more information »](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=62293&IIS70Error=403,14,0x00000000,14393)

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

I have no idea how to access IIS Manager in azure, not even using one. The website is build in React and deployed in azure.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error when I have uploaded my azure application to Azure Windows Web App. The solution was to changed the physical path in the web app settings.

Go to WebApp -> Configuration(Under Settings) -> PathMappings -> Virtual applications and directories.

Here, change the path from site\wwwroot to site\wwwroot{yourdeployedfolder}.

Hope this will work.

Comment: I had to update it to `site\wwwroot\build` since that had the generated files after build.

Answer (score 0):

I spent many hours trying to fix this same issue when I deployed my Angular 8 application to Azure Web App. After trying many things, I fixed this issue by specifying the default document in Azure Web App Configuration settings. It worked. I don't know why Azure Web App was suddenly not recognising the 'index.html' file in the site/wwwroot folder. However adding 'index.html' in the 'Default Documents' section fixed it.

[image]